# Filtering object from one model accordingly to the field of another

Tags: python, django

I am making a new section on a website where existing customers (`Customer` model) can choose to appear on.
New users are not required to have an account from the main site (`Customer`) and can just create an account for the new section (`NewSecUser` model)

```py
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #[...]
    is_visible_on_new_section = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class NewSecUser(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    #[...]
    customer_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    # customer_id refers to the id of a Customer model object 
    # its value is different from null only when a Customer chooses to appear
    # on the new section
```

How would one use `exclude()` to filter-out `NewSecUser` objects where `Customer` objects have an `id` equal to `NewSecUser.customer_id` and `is_visible_on_new_section` set to `False`?

Basically something similar to an SQL `JOIN` (with `new_sec_user.customer_id=customer.id`) I believe.

I know it would have been much easier with `customer_id` being a foreign key but I did not choose this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Customer.filter(id__in = [nsu.pk for nsu in NewSecUser.all()]).filter(is_visible_on_new_selection=True).all()`
```

or something very similar

Comment: I was looking for the opposite but I probably badly formated my question. Your answer was a great help though, exactly what I needed.  
Here is what I was looking for :  


    `NewSecUser.objects.all().filter(customer_id__in = [customer.pk for customer in Customer.objects.all().exclude(is_visible_on_new_section=False)])`  

Thank you!